# Hiding element with display property or left/top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've seen many plugins/ libraries including jQuery mobile that in order to hide 
an element change it's left and/or top properties, as such :

```
div {
   left : 99999px;
   top : 99999px;
}
```

Now this cases many times mess up my code since it's not always disappearing and sometimes increases the scroller to that property, so I found myself editing several plugins and css's to hide elements using `display:none;`

And I keep wondering if maybe there's a reason people choose to do so instead of toggling the display property, or it's just bad practice of said developers.

Is there any preformence difference between these 2 methods? Are there any javascript code that can't run on hidden elements? What would be the better approach?

Comment: I think it's a matter of accessibility: many vocal readers may skip an element with `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by vocal readers, are there tools that describe websites vocally? if ya, then why should they describe an element that should not be seen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR; : Screen readers

Here are the different methods to make an element invisible :

- `display:none;` takes the element out of the flow. The document is rendered as though the element did not exist. So the element is **not vocalized by screen readers**.
- Then you have `visibility:hidden` which makes the box invisible, **but still affects layout**.
- Finally, you have hacks like absolute positioning with offsets to make an element disappear **without affecting the layout** while still **vocalizing it**. Here is an example taken from HTML5 Boilerplate :

  ```
  .visuallyhidden {

      border: 0;
      clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
      height: 1px;
      margin: -1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 1px;
  }
  ```

Comment: What is **vocalizing it**? and where's the `pros` and `cons` when doing it with `absolute` or `display:hidden;`?

Comment: But why would u want to vocalize something that shouldn't be visible? i can understand the affect on the layout, but not this...